# Loading file into R

Tags: r

I am using R for the first time I am trying to save data and again load it , i use this

```
> a <- 1:10
> save(a, file = "desktop/Data.Rdata")
> rm(a)
> load("desktop/Data.Rdata")
```

Warning:

```
 cannot open compressed file 'desktop/Data.Rdata', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Please help me out.

People this works

```
> a <- 1:10
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/saramachandran/Documents"
> save(a,file="Documents/sai.R")
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'Documents/sai.R', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
> save(a,file="/Documents/sai.R")
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file '/Documents/sai.R', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
> save(a,file="C:/Users/saramachandran/Documents/sai.R")
> rm(a)
> load("C:/Users/saramachandran/Documents/sai.R")
> print(a)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you please try this after restarting R in a clean session, and also provide the output of `sessionInfo`?

Comment: I wasnt able to reproduce it either.  I'd imagine it's more system related.

Comment: Could it be that the `save` command failed due to lack of writing permission? Run `getwd()` and try changing it with `setwd(...)`.

Comment: @Sai see my edit below as to what went wrong.  Note that pasting the entire error message is what gave away what was happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using:

```
a <- 1:10
save(a, file = path.expand("~/desktop/Data.Rdata"))
rm(a)
load(path.expand("~/desktop/Data.Rdata"))
```

**EDIT:**

You posted the following...

```
> a <- 1:10
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/saramachandran/Documents"
> save(a,file="Documents/sai.R")
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'Documents/sai.R', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
> save(a,file="/Documents/sai.R")
```

The problem is there  the working directory is already in Documents.  So you're trying to save to:

```
 C:/Users/saramachandran/Documents/Documents
```

This doesn't exist.

Use this instead (or explicitly state the path as you found out):

```
a <- 1:10
save(a, file = "Data.Rdata")
rm(a)
load("Data.Rdata")
```

Comment: Tyler, not sure if using the full path should make a difference if it is being saved and loaded using the same file string.

Comment: It did for me.  I think it depends on your `wd`.  Could also be a Windows thing.

Comment: Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\saramachandran\Documents/desktop/Data.Rdata', probable

Comment: @Ricardo yes I got that message that Sai Vignesh just posted.  Bet I won't get it on the Linux box though.

Comment: but it saved?  Ok try 2 things (1) what Joran requested above; use `sessionInfo()` and paste the contents in your original answer (2)try `file.exists("desktop/Data.Rdata")`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error a couple of times. I solved it by setting my project *As Working Directory*. Click on your project - More - Drop down menu and select "Set As Working Directory." Hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: ... This seems like a very hacky solution :-/

Comment: Thank you, and we can set R's working directory at the command line like so:
setwd("~/NateProjects")